# How can I change telegram verification SMS content

Tags: java, android, telegram

How can I modify telegram SMS verification text content to `MyAppName code xxxxx` instead of `Telegram code xxxxx`?

Comment: The title mismatches with question the content. Currently the question is getting opinion based which is off topic here. I suggest you to edit your question and ask about 'how to change the title' only. 'Which service to choose' should not be included here.

Comment: Thank you Mangesh, I just updated the question as per your recommendation.

Comment: @BirukHailu Telegram Servers send that SMS, you cannot modify/ customize it

Answer (score 0):

This is not Possible. The SMS is sent by Telegram Servers to your prospective users mobile phone.

You're Telegram Client/ Telegram code simply initiates this interaction via the following request:

https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendSms

`auth_sendSms#da9f3e8 phone_number:string phone_code_hash:string = Bool`

Notice that there is no room for customizing this.

Comment: in that case do you think it would be possible to use third party authentication services like twitter digits just for the verification?

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not solve the problem directly, I think it is an okay workaround.

1. Intercept incoming SMS and check if it is from Telegram.
2. If it is read the SMS and delete it right there if it is not let it pass by the default SMS app.
3. Parse the SMS for the verification code and input it automatically to your verification text field.

You probably thought of this already :)

PS: If you like this approach you can learn more about implementing it with this awesome [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-2/).